# Xammp MySQL Error "Bad file descriptor from storage engine MyISAM"

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am getting this error in my phpmyadmin after recently installing new local xammp server.. Can anybody help on this one?

```
Warning in .\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli.class.php#261
 mysqli_query(): (HY000/1030): Got error 9 &quot;Bad file descriptor&quot; from storage engine MyISAM

Backtrace

.\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli.class.php#261: mysqli_query(
object,
string 'SELECT * FROM `mysql`.`db` LIMIT 1',
integer 0,
)
.\libraries\DatabaseInterface.class.php#246: PMA_DBI_Mysqli->realQuery(
string 'SELECT * FROM `mysql`.`db` LIMIT 1',
object,
integer 0,
)
.\libraries\check_user_privileges.lib.php#46: PMA_DatabaseInterface->tryQuery(string 'SELECT * FROM `mysql`.`db` LIMIT 1')
.\libraries\check_user_privileges.lib.php#395: PMA_checkRequiredPrivilgesForAdjust()
.\libraries\List_Database.class.php#17: require_once(.\libraries\check_user_privileges.lib.php)
.\libraries\PMA.php#17: require_once(.\libraries\List_Database.class.php)
.\libraries\common.inc.php#1089: include_once(.\libraries\PMA.php)
.\tbl_structure.php#14: require_once(.\libraries\common.inc.php)
```

Comment: How did you install xamp? was it an upgrqade? Bad file descriptor errors usually refer to corrupt tables, which in your case following a new install or upgrade could be the iussue.

Comment: In addition to the excellent questions asked by apesa, what XAMPP version is this and what phpMyAdmin version is included?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can run this executable file: `mysql_upgrade.exe` which is located inside this folder: `XAMPP/mysql/bin`.. I tried this and it worked.

Comment: While this may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how and why it works.

Comment: Thanks it works.. what it actually does is doing some sort of verification and fixing in case of issues.. anyway I edited your answer to make it more understandable..

Comment: Awesome working fine

Answer (score 7):

I tried mysql_upgrade.exe even with administrator previlage but ot won't work.
for me bellow steps works
But I must do it every day when I start working on localhost.

1. Rename folder mysql/data to mysql/data_old
2. Make a copy of mysql/backup folder and name it as mysql/data
3. Copy all your database folders from mysql/data_old into mysql/data (except mysql, performance_schema, and phpmyadmin folders)
4. Copy mysql/data_old/ibdata1 file into mysql/data folder
5. Start MySQL from XAMPP control panel

Comment: Thank you for this. Running mysql_upgade.exe didn't work for me and at first, this didn't either. MySQL was able to start and I saw my database in phpMyAdmin, but trying to access anything within it threw some sort of "table doesn't exist in the engine" error. I shut down, copied ibdata1 a second time, and it worked then.

Comment: Note that you should also copy, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1... Into the new data folder in order for this to work.

Comment: helped me, with copying  ib_logfile* too

Answer (score 5):

I also received this recently on a fresh install.

1. Start MySQL from XAMPP or from the command line
2. Open command line [Windows] + [r], type "cmd" press [enter]
3. cd \xampp\mysql\bin
4. mysql_upgrade.exe

I found this is happening when I do several mysqldump's from MySQL servers and import them over to MariaDB. The update will check all of your mysql databases, fix table privileges, fixes table and database names, upgrades the tables, and flushes.

Comment: Did you mean mysql_upgrade.exe ? mysql_update.exe doesn't seem to exist

Comment: Yes, I have tried that: mysql_upgrade.exe, it works.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution posted here but it doesn't work (maybe due to Windows and MariaDB). I deciced to do a "quick & dirty" fix.

I navigated to my xampp folder, then /phpmyadmin/libraries/dbi/

Open DBIMysql.class.php - search for

```
if (! $server)
```

should be around line 138, insert before the if statement

```
$user = "your phpmyadmin username";
$password = "your phpmyadmin password";
```

Save the file and use the control to restart MySQL (alias MariaDB). Basically it just overwrites the variables user and password - it seems that the new MariaDB has a problem to receive the password and username in that class. After I did that, no more errors have occured.

But as I mentioned, be careful because this is a very dirty fix.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue for me because I couldn't run the `mysql_upgrade.exe` file. I didn't overwrite the properties though, I set my local root user/pass as default value to the $user and $password parameters of the connect method :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution of this run as adminstrator mysql_upgrade.exe which is located inside this folder: XAMPP/mysql/bin.. I tried this and it work.